# why the php Session wont work for me

Tags: php, session, localhost

**Page1.php**

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test'] = 'abc';
  echo "the Session are set = ".$_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

Result: the Session are set = abc

**page2.php**

```
<?php 
  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION['test'])){
    echo "Session = ";
    echo $_SESSION['test'];
  }else{
    echo "Session are not set";
  }
?>
```

Result: Session are not set

Comment: both pages are in same working location(directory)?if no then it will not work

Comment: check in page2.php to print `print_r($_SESSION)`.

what result found in array.....?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session variables not working php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692157/session-variables-not-working-php)

Comment: Have you executed `page1.php` before `page2.php`?

Comment: yes they are in same folder
C:\xampp\htdocs\Projets\test\page1.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\Projets\test\page2.php

Comment: what os you are using? its might your session directory have problem and your application can't write session to file

Comment: @AbderrahmanElfannir  did you executed first page before 2nd page? check this meanwhile:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/21396172/4248328

Comment: @HarshPanchal he showing void array

Comment: @lkdhruw yes obligatory

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi windows 8.1, i think so too but how to fix it

Comment: @AlivetoDie Yes i did it

Comment: @AbderrahmanElfannir Please try my answer below....

Comment: @PraveenKumar sure

Comment: try `ini_set('session.save_path','path you sure you have permission'));
session_start(); `

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi in page1 or page2?

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi for example ? 
    ini_set('session.save_path','C:/xampp/htdocs/Projets/test/'));

Comment: yes.in both @AbderrahmanElfannir

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi same result

Comment: do you have any other project on your system that use session and work correct?

Comment: i used it in old windows  it was working ,but now i am using new windows and this is my first Session example in the new os, for the old

Comment: cookie is enable in your browser?

Comment: in your php.ini file session.use_cookies is 1 and is not comment or 0 ?

Comment: two files was created it my current folder they are the session files ?

Comment: how an i know if the cookies are enabled or not ?

Comment: session.use_cookies = 1 and he's not comment

Comment: First file named : 'sess_egrj03o91fclno7e813t4buaou' (1kb) contains  test|s:3:"abc";

Comment: where is this file?

Comment: and the second named 'sess_tr21241gogtd7qm9e8trk42nqh' is void

Comment: int same folder location C:\xampp\htdocs\Projets\test

Comment: tnx for all its cookies problem

Answer (score -1):

On page1.php

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test'] = 'abc';
  header("Location: page2.php");//Well we know that this session here works so lets try redirecting...
?>
```

On page2.php Please try

```
<?php 
  if( !session_id() )
  {
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
  }    
  if(isset($_SESSION['test'])){
    echo "Session = ";
    echo $_SESSION['test'];
  }else{
    echo "Session are not set";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Negative markers( If any) please let OP try this code first... :)

Comment: the result of page2.php: Session are not set

Comment: @AbderrahmanElfannir This is working fine at my end on windows OS... https://gyazo.com/b15e33a2f21e421ec5d7a3890e1a0491

Comment: @AbderrahmanElfannir It is working just fine at my end(You can see in screenshot above), But in your, case It is not working So let me know whenever you find a solution for it... :)

Comment: If you think this answer satisfies your needs please mark it as answer... https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: cookies problem , i fix it