# What is wrong with php configuration?

Tags: php, session, php-ini

This is simple php code with sessions:

```
<?php

session_start();

function testSession() {
    //global $_SESSION;
    var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
    echo  " Nope";
    $_SESSION['test'] = " Yeap";
} else {
    testSession();
}
?>
```

The problem is that "$_SESSION" is not a superglobal. "$_SESSION" is undefined in testSession function scope, it is visible only in the main scope. If I uncomment "global $_SESSION" than all will work.

upd:
The error is "Undefined variable: _SESSION" at line var_dump($_SESSION['test']);

upd:
if you write this code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
    echo  " Nope";
    $_SESSION['test'] = " Yeap";
} else {
    var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
}
?>
```

all will work correctly.

Comment: it's a variable scope https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and

Comment: I know that this is a variable scope, but "$_SESSION" array is superglobal by default. That's why it should be available from everywhere without the global keyword.

Comment: Sure, by default when used on its own and not in a method where you didn't pass an argument to

Comment: you also are outputting before header.

Comment: on which line do you getting error

Comment: if I delete "echo "Session test ";" it will not work too.

Comment: Do you know of php's "error reporting"? If you do, use it. If you don't, then Google it and then see what errors show up, if any. Then update your post to contain what those were.

Comment: "var_dump($_SESSION['test']);" <-- this line, $_SESSION is undefined variable

Comment: @funk-forty-niner I have googled the whole day. "Undefined variable: _SESSION" in testSession function

Answer (score 0):

Always put your `session_start();` at the start of the page.

**Try using:**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "Session test ";



function testSession() {
    //global $_SESSION;
    var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
    echo  " Nope";
    $_SESSION['test'] = " Yeap";
} else {
    testSession();
}

?>
```

> 1. Make sure `session_start();` is called before any sessions are being called. So a safe bet would be to put it at the beginning of your page, immediately after the opening `<?php` tag before anything else. Also ensure there are no whitespaces/tabs before the opening `<?php` tag.
> 2. After the `header` redirect, end the current script using `exit();` (Others have also suggested `session_write_close();` and `session_regenerate_id(true)`, you can try those as well, but I'd use `exit();`).
> 3. Make sure cookies are enabled in the browser you are using to test it on.
> 4. Ensure `register_globals` is off, you can check this on the `php.ini` file and also using `phpinfo()`. Refer to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.misc.php#faq.misc.registerglobals) as to how to turn it off.
> 5. Make sure you didn't delete or empty the session.
> 6. Make sure the key in your `$_SESSION` superglobal array is not overwritten anywhere.
> 7. Make sure you redirect to the same domain. So redirecting from a `www.yourdomain.com` to `yourdomain.com` doesn't carry the session forward.
> 8. Make sure your file extension is `.php` (it happens!).

[Session variables not working php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692157/session-variables-not-working-php)