# php session is not set or missing

Tags: php, session

I can't access session data.
In index.php I have this code and `$_SESSION['token']` is not empty:

```
<?php
include "classes/session.php";
include "classes/token.php";
// include "classes/login.php";

use Biboletin\Session;
use Biboletin\Token;
Session::start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Down in the code in the same file i also have line

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>" />
```

This is the method generate() In token.php:

```
public static function generate()
{
    Session::start();
    return Session::set('token', bin2hex(random_bytes(32)));
}
```

The action of the form is pointing to login.php where I `var_dump($_SESSION)` and there is nothing. 
I have `Session::start()` in all files.

And this is the method start():

```
public static function start() 
{ 
  if (!self::$instance) { 
    self::$instance = new self(); 
  }
  return self::$instance;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried  `session_start();` instead of  `Session::start();` ?

Comment: I'm guessing `Session::start()` is part of one of your own classes, please provide the code for the `start` method in your `Session` class.

Comment: Are you getting "Headers already sent" warnings in `login.php`? If so, you have to fix that.

Comment: Did you start your session in login.php?

Comment: I'll try tomorrow with session_start();

Comment: And this is the method start(): 
`    public static function start()
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }`

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code to your question, instead of as a comment. With that said, you need `session_start` in there, dude. Sessions in PHP won't start without it.

Comment: I'm guessing `session_start()` is in the `Session` constructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session variables not working php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692157/session-variables-not-working-php)

Comment: @Martin no its different problem and the link provided dont fixed my problem

Comment: You need to show *why* it's a different problem. You code looks completely wrong. You should show us your `phpinfo` output as well as your full `Session` class , please.

Comment: https://github.com/biboletin/php/blob/master/session.php this is the session class(please dont laught at it :D ) i saw the class in one site - i think it was stack exchange and i get the idea and i improvise with the code a little