# after refresh the page its logout what i can do?

Tags: php, mysql

after refresh page its logout from system

this code for session:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "<script>window.location.href='login.php'</script>";

    exit;
    }

$check_session=$db->countRecords("select * from user_sessions where username='".$_SESSION["username"]."' and session_id='".$_SESSION["session_id"]."'");


if($check_session<=0)
    {

        session_start();
        session_destroy();
    echo "<script>window.location.href='login.php'</script>";

    }

    $last_month=date("Y-m-1",strtotime("-1 Months")); 


    $delete_session=$db->Delete_Record("admin_sessions"," session_date<='".$last_month."'");
?>
```

Comment: <?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
 echo "<script>window.location.href='login.php'</script>";
 
 exit;
 }

$check_session=$db->countRecords("select * from user_sessions where username='".$_SESSION["username"]."' and session_id='".$_SESSION["session_id"]."'");


if($check_session<=0)
 {
 
  session_start();
  session_destroy();
 echo "<script>window.location.href='login.php'</script>";
 
 }
 
 $last_month=date("Y-m-1",strtotime("-1 Months")); 
 
 
 $delete_session=$db->Delete_Record("admin_sessions"," session_date<='".$last_month."'");
?>

Comment: `session_start();` has to go to the most top of your file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session variables not working php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692157/session-variables-not-working-php)