# How do I pass my generated API token as my authorization bearer

Tags: php, api, curl, customization, code-snippets

I have trying this all day, but couldn't find a way out.

I have two codes; the first one generates an AccessToken that will be used to call an API. I also parsed the Json output so that, I can have only the AccessToken parameter displayed... Here's the code;

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sandbox.monnify.com/api/v1/auth/login/");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

  "Content-Type: application/json",

  "Authorization: Basic TUtfVEVTVF9TQUY3SFI1RjNGOjRTWTZUTkw4Q0szVlBSU0JUSFRSRzJOOFhYRUdDNk5M"

));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$token = json_decode($response, true);

$at = $token['responseBody'];

echo $at['accessToken'];

curl_close($ch);
```

The above code outputs the token.

Now, this is the code that sends the request below;

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

  CURLOPT_URL => "https://sandbox.monnify.com/api/v1/bank-transfer/reserved-accounts/ogmic1",

  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",

  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,

  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,

  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,

  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,

  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",

  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(

    "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsibW9ubmlmeS1wYXltZW50LWVuZ2luZSJdLCJzY29wZSI6WyJwcm9maWxlIl0sImV4cCI6MTYwMTE0MDA0MywiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiTVBFX1JFVFJJRVZFX1JFU0VSVkVEX0FDQ09VTlQiLCJNUEVfREVMRVRFX1JFU0VSVkVEX0FDQ09VTlQiLCJNUEVfUkVUUklFVkVfUkVTRVJWRURfQUNDT1VOVF9UUkFOU0FDVElPTlMiLCJNUEVfSU5JVElBTElaRV9QQVlNRU5UIiwiTVBFX1JFU0VSVkVfQUNDT1VOVCIsIk1QRV9DQU5fUkVUUklFVkVfVFJBTlNBQ1RJT04iXSwianRpIjoiNmQ0OTA0ZDQtMzNjYy00Y2NlLWI3OTgtODg3ZjdlOTEwM2JhIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiTUtfVEVTVF9TQUY3SFI1RjNGIn0.jqjtn8uyVxSL8oVPNHojMRzqiPx__xYTzoPCsi5IJgiXd184Nc6XSp7QaZlbav6NjXQAt8uuYWVuEqZpJoHJSJlvR-QbpV_pkx582EV0cGdTNzFAUgyrRYvWxmFmNeS-XBVk0-8labvDqyLHcpjfoT_FaiBylY2ek99G8WvXxnvLE1STY91blhMb3UCKBykDzVlmX0U6gvWd9Btgb1-Zb18Olt-GHmsYavBDSvSpptSiIleFPsZzL1O_u366DVMmGrCq-1iqYpBBRixU0uslTsp17VJfvHJUwciPSHDDaPK2iH6QP7Nv4jPYMNhs8MW7L67NYO9yohD9qfAOTyWv6g"

  ),

));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$objs = json_decode($response, true);

$rp = $objs['responseBody'];
 
echo "<div class='dlmenu1'> <span style='background:#fff;color:#295f2d;font-size:13px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;padding:2px;margin-right:3px;'>" .
$rp['accountNumber'] . "</span>";
echo "<span style='background:#fff;color:#295f2d;font-size:13px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;padding:2px;margin-right:3px;'>(" . $rp['bankName'] . ")</span>";
echo "<span style='background:#fff;color:#295f2d;font-size:13px;text-align:center;padding:2px;margin-right:3px;'>"  . " - Instant Funding</span></div>";

curl_close($curl);
```

I need help on how I can pass the AccessToken generated in the first code to the second one (the two codes combined), so that it can serve as the Authorization Bearer.
I don't mind if the two codes can be combined.

Thanks

Comment: Are these actual credentials you posted?

Comment: Yes, I posted the actual basic authorization code for testing purpose

Comment: You shouldn't post credentials here ... For obvious reasons

Comment: These are test keys... They are not for production. The API link is also a for testing purpose not for production.

Comment: OK, just wanted to mention it ... As for your problem: Have you tried using session variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692157/session-variables-not-working-php

Comment: No.. just checked. Don't know how it works

Comment: Well. Then you should find some documentation and try it. Because session variables are the way to store values between multiple requests for the same user ...