# PHP deduct value from main value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a game where a player is given initial investment (at random by an investor). This becomes their budget to spend on products. I'm trying to code so that when they buy a product (they can buy multiple of the same ones) that it reflects in the budget by deducting its cost. I keep getting the insufficient budget error, and I'm not sure why when there's enough money.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Investment Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Investment Game</h1>
    <p>Your budget is: $<span id="budget">...</span></p>

    <h2>Products:</h2>
    <ul id="products">
    </ul>

    <script>
        // Get the initial budget and product list when the page loads
        fetch('getInitialData.php').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
            document.getElementById('budget').innerText = data.budget;

            const productsElement = document.getElementById('products');
            data.products.forEach(product => {
                const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                listItem.innerHTML = `${product.name} ($${product.price}) 
                                      <button onclick="buyProduct('${product.name}', ${product.price})">Buy</button>`;
                productsElement.appendChild(listItem);
            });
        });

        // Function to buy a product
        function buyProduct(name, price) {
            fetch('buyProduct.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({productName: name, price: price}),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if(data.success) {
                    document.getElementById('budget').innerText = data.newBudget;
                } else {
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

buyProduct.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$inputData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$productName = $inputData['productName'];
$price = $inputData['price'];

// Check if user has enough budget
if($_SESSION['budget'] >= $price) {
    $_SESSION['budget'] -= $price;
    echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "newBudget" => $_SESSION['budget']));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => "Insufficient budget"));
}
?>
```

getInitialData.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$investors = array(
    "Fred" => 24000,
    "Barney" => 32000
);

// Assign a random investor's budget to session if not already set
if (!isset($_SESSION['budget'])) {
    $randomInvestor = array_rand($investors);
    $_SESSION['budget'] = $investors[$randomInvestor];
}

// Example product list
$products = array(
    array("name" => "Product 1", "price" => 100),
    array("name" => "Product 2", "price" => 150)
);

// Return initial data as JSON
echo json_encode(array("budget" => $_SESSION['budget'], "products" => $products));
?>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce (albeit in a slightly split online demo, out of necessity): https://3v4l.org/MYunj (simulates getInitialData.php, to get the JSON), then https://jsfiddle.net/sex468k0/ (simulates the web page receiving the JSON and then generating new JSON after a Buy button is press), then https://3v4l.org/Tr8dU (simulates buyProduct.php with hard-coded JSON as was generated by the JSFiddle fetch() request)

Comment: I also brought locally and could not reproduce either. To debug this, you'll need to inspect `$_SESSION['budget']` and `$price`. One way to do that would be to include them in the JSON payload, too, just for inspection purposes.

Comment: @Chris Haas 
Having commented out the else in the buyProduct.php, I'm not getting 'Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input' in the console. So is it something to do with that it's not pulling it through correctly as JSON?

Comment: Possibly. Use the Network tool in your browser to examine the raw response coming back from the server, and see what's really there

Comment: Responses are all 200 and ok, and in the payload, I'm getting {
  "productName": "Product 1",
  "price": 100
} as a response. So I'm stumped :(

Comment: "Payload" is what you're _sending_ to the server. The "response" tab contains what comes back - that's where you need to look

Comment: P.s. `Having commented out the else in the buyProduct.php`...it's a bit unclear why you did this?

Comment: So far, the code worked for me with no problem ! Is this still an open question ?

Comment: @ADyson - I was trying to debug because the response is always {"success":false,"message":"Insufficient budget"} in the response tab for buyProduct.php

Comment: @hanifzekri - still open because I'm still not getting the correct response - always 
{"success":false,"message":"Insufficient budget"}

Comment: @ADyson Hardcoding the session budget and json elements in buyProduct.php kind of works - the response is correct, but the budget never changes regardless of whatever you buy

Comment: @user47467 I think removing that `else` has led to the `Unexpected end of JSON input` because now there might be no response coming back from the server all in that scenario. There must be something else odd going on. Maybe sessions are not working properly in your environment or something, because 3 of us are unable to reroduce your issue. You don't seem to have done Chris' debugging suggestion yet, which was to test what's actually in your Session and in your $price variable when the code runs. You could either add it to the JSON response temporarily, or log it to a file.

Comment: @ADyson having added them into the JSON payload, I get this response {"success":false,"message":"Insufficient budget","budget":null,"price":150}
So I guess something is up with the session?

Comment: Thanks. It seems likely. Just to double-check, in the request to `getInitialData.php` you are getting the original budget value back correctly, is that so?

Comment: If so then it does seem the session might not be saving properly. Do you have PHP set to log errors and warnings into a log file? If so, check for that. (If not, enable it, re-run the code and then check to see if any session-related warnings appear). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692157/session-variables-not-working-php is probably also a good resource to start from too - and you can easily google more. WIthout direct access to your environment and in the absence, so far, of an error about it, it's difficult for me to do more than point to you known suggestions for things to look at

Comment: @ADyson Yes - getting {"budget":24000,"products":[{"name":"Product 1","price":100},{"name":"Product 2","price":150}]} for `getInitialData.php` and other values when budget is chosen at random.

Will look at log files now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - looks like I had permission issues to start sessions.

By adding `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of PHP files, I was able to see warning messages of `Permission denied`.

Before the call to `session_start()`, I put in a call to `session_save_path()` and gave it the name of a directory writable by the server.